# заполнение коллекции в pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть функция, которая в теории должна заполнять коллекцию данными из какой-либо таблицы. На вход подается строка запроса и строка столбцов, обрамленных тегами, которые нужно вывести. Например:

```
select f1('select * from a', '<#ID#>') from dual
```

Вот сама функция:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(QUERY IN VARCHAR2, VALUESES VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
 cur PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;   
 cols DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;   
 ncols PLS_INTEGER; 
 answer VARCHAR2(30000);
 parsing varchar2(30000);
 TYPE pol is table of number;
 pol1 pol;
BEGIN  
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE      
  (cur, query, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);   
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS (cur, ncols, cols);    
  FOR colind IN 1 .. ncols   
    LOOP   
      parsing := '<#'||cols (colind).col_name||'#>';
      if parsing = regexp_substr(VALUESES, '<#[[:alpha:]]+#>') then 
        pol1 := set(dbms_sql.column_value(cur, ncols, pol1)); 
      end if;  
    END LOOP;   
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR (cur); 
  return answer;
END;
```

Но ничего не выходит. Как занести данные в коллекцию? Ну и как потом данные оттуда забрать, чтобы вернуть answer?

Comment: А суть задачи можете пояснить? Пока это выглядит как попытка почесать правое ухо левой пяткой. Например, в теле функции вы заполняете коллекцию, а на выход подаете строковую переменную `answer`, которая вообще никак в теле функции не используется и ничем не заполняется.

Comment: Еще смущает то, что вы хотите таким образом "обрамлять тэгами". Может, [SQL/XML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB1600) спасет отца русской демократии?